# Variable data attribute not working

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++){
$('#container').append('<div class="content"><span class="context-text" data-item="' + i '">' + subject[i].title + '</span></div>');
}
```

It is not working. This does work:

```
for(var i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++){
$('#container').append('<div class="content"><span class="context-text" data-item="1">' + subject[i].title + '</span></div>');
}
```

Can anybody help? I am missing something and I don't see what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Might be you have missed to add one `+` sign. Here `data-item="' + i '"`.

Comment: You're missing a `+` after `i`. Also note that you loop through `subjects` but attempt to access `subject` within the loop. Voting to close as both problems are just typos

Comment: In fact JavaScript does not work at all. Usually that is the case when there is a syntax-error. But I can't find any. When I replace ' + i' by 1 it works perfectly.

Comment: For future reference always check the console when debugging JS code. You would have seen a syntax error in this case

Comment: @ Rory: Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed + after i

Change this line

```
$('#container').append('<div class="content"><span class="context-text" data-item="' + i '">' + subject[i].title + '</span></div>');
```

to

```
$('#container').append('<div class="content"><span class="context-text" data-item="' + i + '">' + subject[i].title + '</span></div>');
```

Comment: Thank you Kenny, I have been staring at it for at least an hour.